# Netbeans hangs out on loading modules

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, freeze

I use Netbeans 7.1 at work, with multiple Maven projects opened ad the same time, running those Java /J2EE projects on a Glassfish 2.0 Server.

Everytime I open Netbeans it hangs out when Loading Modules. To make it work I must delete the .netbeans folder.

Why is this happening? I've asked the technical support team but they have no idea.

I've also tryed most recent versions of Netbeans and the problem persist.

I've also noticed that, when it hangs out, occupies RAM memory over 400MB and then stops.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What plugins did you install? Try removing them and adding them one by one to rule out one of these is the culprit.

Comment: Only Glassfish plugin is installed.

Comment: What Maven projects do you have? Are they huge projects? Does it really hang, or does it just take a while to load?

Comment: Yes, there are huge projects. And yes, it hangs out (I left it 30 minutes loading, and it has devoured almost all the RAM and crashed the PC)

Comment: The only thing I could imagine that could go wrong is that there are files in your projects that are of a considerable size. However, if Netbeans runs correctly after removing the `.netbeans` directory, that probably isn't the issue. Maybe you're better off going through [Netbeans Bugzilla](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/) and possibly file a bug report. Also, Netbeans 7.1 is a bit old. Have you tried Netbeans 7.4?

Comment: I've tried it but the problem persists. Maybe I will open a bug report. Thanks.